# Why is my SQL statement behaving this way when using AND or OR - Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a form with two radio buttons(SSOP or SCOP), six checkboxes and 1 combobox. Based on the radio button choice, the combobox gets populated then filtered with the checkboxes (multiple checkboxes can be chosen)

I have written the code below and when i choose only checkbox it works perfectly, displaying only the SSOP of that checkbox. But when i choose more than one checkbox it shows me both the SSOP and the SCOP. as if the LIKE statement is bypassed. Why is that?

Thanks

```
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnSearch.Click

 SQLa = "SELECT * FROM ARES_Procedure_List WHERE ARES_ID LIKE '%SSOP%' "
        Dim strChk As String = ""
        Dim chk As CheckBox
        Dim strSubsystem As String = ""
        Dim listSubsystem As List(Of [String]) = New List(Of String)
        For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
                chk = DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox)
                If chk.Checked = True Then
                    listSubsystem.Add("Subsystem = '" & 
         Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(chk.Text, 1) & "'")

                End If
            End If

        Next
        strSubsystem = [String].Join(" OR ", listSubsystem.ToArray())
        Label1.Text = strSubsystem
        SQLa = SQLa & "AND " & strSubsystem & ""
        MsgBox(SQLa)
        CallAccess()
        cboSelect.Items.Clear()
        Do Until RSa.EOF()
        cboSelect.Items.Add(RSa.Fields("ARES_ID").Value)
        RSa.MoveNext()
        Loop
        CloseAccess()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the correct order of evaluation of your logical operators adding parenthesys around the sequence of OR conditions

```
SQLa = SQLa & "AND (" & strSubsystem & ")"
```

However, you should add some control on the state of your checkboxes. If none of them is checked your code builds an invalid SQL

```
if listSubsystem.Count > 0 Then
    strSubsystem = [String].Join(" OR ", listSubsystem.ToArray())
    Label1.Text = strSubsystem
    SQLa = SQLa & "AND (" & strSubsystem & ")"
End If
```

Side note. The check loop could be rewritten and shortened with

```
    For Each chk In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        If chk.Checked Then
            listSubsystem.Add("Subsystem = '" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(chk.Text, 1) & "'")

       End If
    Next
```

Filtering and casting is done directly in the OfType(Of CheckBox) IEnumerable extension

Comment: Wow. This is perfect! Thank you so much!